# Check if a ComboBox Contains Item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Content" x:Name="cb">
  <ComboBoxItem>Combo</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>Box</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>Item</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

If I use

```
cb.Items.Contains("Combo")
```

or

```
cb.Items.Contains(new ComboBoxItem {Content = "Combo"})
```

it returns `False`.

Can anyone tell me how do I check if a `ComboBoxItem` named `Combo` exists in the `ComboBox` `cb`?

Comment: The ComboBox does not have a names so how are you referencing it?

Comment: It is best to post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: If you are looking for speed then bind the source to a HashSet of string and test if the HashSet contains the string.  If you need dynamic inserts and deletes then ObservableCollection.  Using the ComboBox as the collection is not optimal.

Comment: @Blam Can't use a `HashSet` since I am styling some of the `ComboBoxItem`s.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Items is an `ItemCollection` and `not list of strings`. In your case its a `collection of ComboboxItem` and you need to check its `Content` property.

```
cb.Items.Cast<ComboBoxItem>().Any(cbi => cbi.Content.Equals("Combo"));
```

OR

```
cb.Items.OfType<ComboBoxItem>().Any(cbi => cbi.Content.Equals("Combo"));
```

You can loop over each item and break in case you found desired item -

```
bool itemExists = false;
foreach (ComboBoxItem cbi in cb.Items)
{
    itemExists = cbi.Content.Equals("Combo");
    if (itemExists) break;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it. `Contains` also internally loops over entire list till it found a desired element.

Comment: Yeah you can use `OfType` in place of `Cast`.

Comment: Updated with another approach.

Comment: Yes, that is the fastest of the 3 and I am currently using that. Check this : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ARCcpF80

Comment: Nice observation. So, you still looking for some other alternative?

Comment: Yup, I already had the Loop option in mind before I asked the question.

Comment: @Don'tForgettoUpvote If you don't mind to use another collection then sync Items in your combobox with `Dictionary<K,V>` and check the dictionary rather than checking Combobox It will improve performance, but not a good solution though

Comment: No, I can't use any `Collection` since I am styling some of the `ComboBoxItem`s. I think I will have to do with the Loop option. I don't think there are any other alternatives.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the `Contains` function as in `cb.Items.Contains("Combo")` you have to add strings to your ComboBox, not ComboBoxItems: `cb.Items.Add("Combo")`. The string will display just like a ComboBoxItem.

Answer (score 0):

**In C# Winform Apps You can do the following:**

//Create a function like below

```c#
internal static bool CheckCombo(ComboBox.ObjectCollection items, string Search)
{
    bool isFound = false;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (item.Equals(Search))
        {
            isFound = true; break;
        }
    }
    return isFound;
}
```

You can call the function like this when adding your items to the combo box

```html
if (!Functions.CheckCombo(Combobox.Items, "ValueToSearch"))
{
  //Adding the value if is not found in the combobox
  Combobox.Items.Add("ValueToSearch");
}
```